# JavaScript function to returning array

Tags: javascript, arrays, return

I have the following code:

```
var disArray = ['red','red','green','green','green','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue'];
var otherArray = [];


function takeOut() {
    for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        var randItem = disArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*disArray.length)];
        otherArray.push(randItem);
    }
    return otherArray;
}

takeOut(disArray)
console.log(otherArray)
```

I want the function to return the elements in `otherArray` when it is called, but it I get the error `undefined`. It only works when I `console.log` `otherArray`. Is there any way that I can make the function return the array without using `console.log`?

Comment: otherArray = takeOut(disArray);
console.log(otherArray);

Comment: `otherArray` is not in the scope of the function.

Comment: `undefined` is not an error. You don’t even get any error.

Comment: Your function returns the array regardless of whether you call `console.log`. I'm not able to reproduce the `undefined` value. Just do `console.log(takeOut(disArray))`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a local variable.

```js
function takeOut() {
    var otherArray = [], i, randItem;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        randItem = disArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * disArray.length)];
        otherArray.push(randItem);
    }
    return otherArray;
}

var disArray = ['red','red','green','green','green','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue'],
    result = takeOut(disArray);

console.log(result);
```

For a reusable function, you could add some parameters to the function, like the array and the count, you need.

```js
function takeOut(array, count) {
    var result = [];
    while (count--) {
        result.push(array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)]);
    }
    return result;
}

var disArray = ['red','red','green','green','green','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue'],
    result = takeOut(disArray, 5);

console.log(result);
```

Example for calling `takeOut` multiple times and store the result in an array.

```js
function takeOut(array, count) {
    var result = [];
    while (count--) {
        result.push(array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)]);
    }
    return result;
}

var disArray = ['red','red','green','green','green','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue'],
    i = 7,
    result = []

while (i--) {
    result.push(takeOut(disArray, 5));
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: More specifically, you are using the return value of `takeOut()` and passing it in to `console.log`.

Comment: right. the result set is independent from the former variable `otherArray`, now.

Comment: You should also add `disArray` as a parameter in the function declaration, so that it can use any array as a parameter and not just the global. Right now passing `takeOut()` a parameter does nothing.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Is there any way to use this functions multiple times for it to return different results ?

Comment: that it usually the idea behind functions -- reusable and with `Math.random` it should return for every call a different result.

Comment: What I mean by that is to return a result, keep the result, and then return another rezult and also keep it. I'm sorry if you dont understand whay I'm trying to say, im a begginer. Put more simple, is there any way for the function to return 5 different otherArray with different results in it ?

Comment: you can move the result of a call into an array. please see edit.

Comment: @TudorApostol No, a function can only return one thing. That one thing can however be an object or array that contains multiple things.

Comment: Thank you, Nina. I will look through the code and try to understand how it works.

Comment: For the purpose of not opening another question. I am trying to assign a html div to an array element, lets say Im trying to assign to 'red'. Is there the option, when I'm calling the array, instead of returning the string 'red', it could return the element im trying to assign to it ?

Comment: yes, you can use any other value, even an object, or the reference to one.

Answer (score 0):

Basically a call to takeOut() is returning a value using a return. If you want to print on the console, you need to pass it to the console.log() fn. The other way is to assign the fn call ie. takeOut() to a variable and direct the variable to the console or use elsewhere.

```js
var disArray = ['red','red','green','green','green','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue'];
var otherArray = [];


function takeOut() {
    for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        var randItem = disArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*disArray.length)];
        otherArray.push(randItem);
    }
    return otherArray;
}

takeOut()  //need to utilize the returned variable somewhere.
console.log(takeOut())  //prints to stackoverflow.com result // inspect browser console
```